# Svelte multipage website with Vite DevTool

Tags: svelte, vite, multi-page-application

I'm trying to build a multi-page site with Svelte using Vite.
According to the picture below (Vite documentation), I can just add a folder with index.html in it.
[image: Vite documentation]

I tried it but it doesn't work. When I visit localhost:5173/about it keeps opening the Homepage. Here's my folder structure

[image: My folder structure]

Anyone how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

It's a defect on vite's part. See [#6596](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6596). If you really need to config the behavior differently, this [issue comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6596#issuecomment-1114363584) provides a solution. If it doesn't bother you much, just add a trailing slash to that path and live with it until vite team resolve the issue.

```
localhost:5173/about  # this doesn't work
localhost:5173/about/ # this works
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using Svelte (not SvelteKit)? I was facing the same problem with Svelte, and then I tried to install 3rd party library for routing but it didn't work as I expected. I solve the problem by switching to SvelteKit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the latest version of sveltekit, `about.js` in your screenshot is not a valid route. Instead, change it to `routes/about/+page.svelte` & `routes/about/+page.js`. This was part of recent changes the svelte team implemented ahead of the upcoming 1.0 release. More [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page).